# Getting 404 error with a new CNAME RR

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

Our server is authoritative for "example.com". If someone puts in example.com in a web browser, we need it to redirect to domain2.com. Since you cant have a CNAME RR for the root zone name, I tried to point www for example.com to domain2.com, as follows:

```
www             IN CNAME        domain2.com.
```

This works with Dig - meaning I run dig and it finds the CNAME for www.example.com. But, in a web browser, I put in www.example.com and I get a 404 not found error. I do not get re-directed to domain2.com.

Here are the Dig results for domian2.com:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
domain2.com. 17 IN  CNAME   anotherdomain.com.
anotherdomain.com. 140  IN  A   192.168.1.100
anotherdomain.com. 140  IN  A   192.168.1.100
```

So it has its own CNAME with 2 identical A records. Not sure if this is a problem. I am hoping someone can tell me what I am doing wrong, how to fix it or if this CNAME to another CNAME business won't work. NOTE - doing the redirect in code is not an option at this point. Need a DNS solution if possible.

Comment: DNS is not HTTP! You can't do an HTTP redirect in DNS.

Comment: I have researched this more and actually you can. However, steps will need to be taken on the webserver to allow content to be served to both domains once you have created the CNAME. For instance in apache you'd add example.com as a virtual host/alias. So while a pure solution with code is more of a true redirect, this combination of CNAME/alias works as well.

Comment: That's done in the web server, not in DNS! Though DNS is only a component of it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do what you want to do in the way that you want to do it - the internet does not work in the way that you seem to think it does...

When you enter `http://www.example.com/test/index.html` into your web browser, amongst other things example.com is harvested and used to create a [Host: header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) (section 14.3 refers)

The name www.example.com is also is also used to resolve the IP address of the server. In your case that initially resolves to a series of CNAMEs so an additional DNS request is made for each until the IP address is resolved.

Because the url starts with http://, a TCP connection is made to port 80 of the IP address that was eventually resolved.

A webserver may be configured to answer for many domains. When you connect to it, it does not know which of those domain you are calling. That's where the host header is used

```
   GET /test/index.html HTTP/1.1
   Host: www.example.com
```

This tells the webserver to supply /test/index.html from the virtual host configured to respond to www.example.com.

Note that the only use of your CNAME records was to look up the server address. It has not affected the host header at all.

To solve your problem you need to configure the virtualhost at www.example.com to respond with a redirect to your other domain.

Answer (score 2):

DNS is the phone book. In it, you say "To reach `www.domain2.com`, call `192.168.1.100`".

The web server is what answers the phone at `192.168.1.100`. When it picks up the phone, it has no idea what the caller (that is, the user's web browser) read in the phone book earlier. So it's going to say "Hi, this is `anotherdomain.com`, how can I help you?", and the user's browser will be confused. For things to work, you have to tell the web server that when someone calls `192.168.1.100`, it's supposed to answer for both `www.domain2.com` and `anotherdomain.com`.

You can't make the web server automatically know what names for it someone put in the phone book. You have to tell it explicitly (normally via its config files). It that doesn't seem obvious to you, consider the case of some confused person in Farawayistan accidentally writing in their local phone book that `my.pretty.horse` has number `192.168.1.100` when they really meant to write that it has `192.168.100.1`. There is no way that you or your web server could possibly know that happened.